# AngularJS filter on deep properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter some data on a string value but I can't get the syntax right.  Here is my code :

```
<tbody ng-repeat="qbRating in vm.scope.qbRatings | filter:'tournament.season.seasonName':'2022'  | ratingFilter | orderBy:'-rating'">
    <tr class="qbrating2022">
        <td>{{ qbRating.tournament.season.seasonName }}</td>
        <td>{{ qbRating.team.teamName }}</td>
        <td>{{ qbRating.completion }}</td>
        <td>{{ qbRating.gain }}</td>
        <td>{{ qbRating.touchdown }}</td>
        <td>{{ qbRating.interception }}</td>
        <td>{{ qbRating.rating }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The filter does not return any data even though it should do, but there is no error returned in the console.

Can anybody help me get the syntax right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put filter on specific property by specifying object to be match like `filter: {'tournament': {season : {seasonName:'2022'}}}`

```
ng-repeat="qbRating in vm.scope.qbRatings | filter: {'tournament': {season : {seasonName:'2022'}}} | ratingFilter | orderBy:'-rating'"
```

Comment: Excellent, just the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @user517406 Glad to know that.Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

filter takes a string, object or function, not an array [filter api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: My mistake, the filter should be filter:'tournament.season.seasonName':'2022', but it does not return anything. See edit

Comment: @user517406 ok) second argument is a comparator and should be a function, true or undefined